# Which languages or tools are used to code google analytics

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

I just want to know that which languages or tools did google use ongoogle analytics.

I mean when we insert the javascript piece of code o our web page then which piece of software ctaches that result and which langauage they do some calculation and then how do they display graphs.

If some has any idea

Comment: Why does it matter what particular technology they use for it? We can't know unless Google have published the information, we work for Google or we can spot enough of a finger print on the output to take an educated guess. It would probably be much more useful and interesting to ask for recommendations about what technologies we would use to get the same effects (noting that "Capturing data from browsers" and "Generating graphs" are very discrete tasks and best suited to separate questions).

Comment: Google uses mainly Java and Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at how google analytics frontend is implemented, that is most likely using [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) deducing by the type of interactivity there.

Each page view is sent through the embedded js to some webserver and then onto some backend servers on the google side over http. Language used for backend processing used by google  should be irrelevant to you. You can pick any language of your choice for implementing similar things.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad (to the point of being virtually unanswerable) question.  This link:

http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55539

provides some very basic explanation of the analytics mechanism, but if you really want to know what Google is doing sever-side ... go work for Google ;-)

Seriously though, whatever you are trying to accomplish, it almost certainly makes more sense for you to use languages and tools that are suited for your goals, rather than trying to mimic Google's choice of programming language and tools.

To that end there are a number of different languages/frameworks you could choose for the server-side:

- Ruby/Rails
- Python/Django
- PHP/Cake
- Java/JSP
- Java/JSF
- Older stuff like Perl/cgi-bin

If I had to guess, Google is probably using Java + their own framework, but again for you there is no "right" answer, only what's right for you.  If you have experience with Python, go read up on Django; if you don't but know Ruby, Rails is great, etc.  Once you've picked the language/framework for your project, a quick Google search for the language + "charts" (eg. "Python charts") should turn up *at least* one solid charting library you can use ... unless you just want to do your charting in Javascript, in which case there are like half a million (I swear a new one comes out every minute) different charting libraries to choose from.